# get the value of $scope when in function in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Unable to get the value of $scope when in function in angular js

Here how it looks like

```
module.controller('MainController', function($scope, $window, $rootScope, checkConnection) {
    $scope.online = false;
    $scope.deviceReady = false;
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        checkConnection.checkCon($scope);
        $scope.checkInetNetwork = $rootScope.checkInetNetwork;

        if ($rootScope.checkInetNetwork == "true") {
            $scope.online = true;
        } else {
            $scope.online = false;
        }
    }
});
```

I am not able to figure out why `<p ng-show="online">ThAnk You Thank you</p>` why this is not displaying. When even i am making it TRUE. Out side this function it works like charm.

Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you are changing the scope value outside of the angular digest cycle.

You can call $apply to run the digest cycle to fix it

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    checkConnection.checkCon($scope);
    $scope.checkInetNetwork = $rootScope.checkInetNetwork;

    if ($rootScope.checkInetNetwork == "true") {
        $scope.online = true;
    } else {
        $scope.online = false;
    }

    $scope.$apply();
}
```

---

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    checkConnection.checkCon($scope);
    $scope.checkInetNetwork = $rootScope.checkInetNetwork;

    $scope.online = $rootScope.checkInetNetwork == "true";

    $scope.$apply();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to run a `$scope.$apply` as something has happened outside of Angular's knowledge.

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    checkConnection.checkCon($scope);
    $scope.checkInetNetwork = $rootScope.checkInetNetwork;

    if($rootScope.checkInetNetwork == "true"){
        $scope.online = true;
    }
    else
    {
        $scope.online = false;
    }
    $scope.$apply();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$rootScope.online = false` instead of `$scope.online = false` so you can have an access of the $scope everywhere you want to call this.

Comment: No this method is not workable. But yeah thank you so much for support

Comment: Sorry, I thought that you can't have access to your $scope! :)
You're welcome! :)